# How to prove the KL Divergence integral exists?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, information-theory

Given pdfs $p(x), q(x)$, how can I show that the following integral exists?
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x)\log\left( \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right)dx
\end{align*}
where we follow the conventions from [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362860/kl-divergence-between-which-distributions-could-be-infinity).

I'm not sure how to approach this. I found [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability) on wikipedia, but it seems to not be very useful, since this function is not bounded, nor on a compact interval. Also, this function can take the value $\infty$.

If anyone could provide a resource for techniques on showing integrability, that would be greatly appreciated.